# Error Codigo Javascript To-Do List

Tags: javascript, html, lista

Tengo un problema con este código javascript, que no se exactamente donde tenga mi error (creo que es en `function clearCompleted`)

Lo que quiero lograr es que los botones en este código HTML

```js
const lista = document.querySelector('#lista')
const elemento = document.querySelector('#elemento')
const input = document.querySelector('#input')
const botonEnter = document.querySelector('#boton-enter')
const check = 'fa-check-circle'
const uncheck = 'fa-circle'
const lineThrough = 'line-through'
const clearBtn = document.getElementById("clear");
const saveBtn = document.getElementById("save");
const emptyBtn = document.getElementById("empty");
let LIST

let id // para que inicie en 0 cada tarea tendra un id diferente

// funcion de agregar tarea 

function agregarTarea( tarea,id,realizado,eliminado) {
    if(eliminado) {return} // si existe eliminado es true si no es false 

    const REALIZADO = realizado ? check : uncheck // si realizado es verdadero check si no uncheck

    const LINE = realizado ? lineThrough : '' 

    const elemento = `
                        <li id="elemento">
                        <i class="fa ${REALIZADO} co" data="realizado" id="${id}"></i>
                        <p class="text ${LINE}">${tarea}</p>
                        <i class="fa fa-trash de" data="eliminado" id="${id}"></i> 
                        </li>
                    `
    lista.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend",elemento)

}


// funcion de Tarea Realizada 

function tareaRealizada(element) {
    element.classList.toggle(check)
    element.classList.toggle(uncheck)
    element.parentNode.querySelector('.text').classList.toggle(lineThrough)
    LIST[element.id].realizado = LIST[element.id].realizado ?false :true //Si
   // console.log(LIST)
   // console.log(LIST[element.id])
   // console.log(LIST[element.id].realizado)
}

function tareaEliminada(element){
   // console.log(element.parentNode)
   // console.log(element.parentNode.parentNode)
    element.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(element.parentNode)
    LIST[element.id].eliminado = true
    console.log(LIST)
}





// crear un evento para escuchar el enter y para habilitar el boton 

botonEnter.addEventListener('click', ()=> {
    const tarea = input.value
    if(tarea){
        agregarTarea(tarea,id,false,false)
        LIST.push({
            nombre : tarea,
            id : id,
            realizado : false,
            eliminado : false
        })
        localStorage.setItem('TODO',JSON.stringify(LIST))
        id++
        input.value = ''
    }

})

document.addEventListener('keyup', function (event) {
    if (event.key=='Enter'){
        const tarea = input.value
        if(tarea) {
            agregarTarea(tarea,id,false,false)
        LIST.push({
            nombre : tarea,
            id : id,
            realizado : false,
            eliminado : false
        })
        localStorage.setItem('TODO',JSON.stringify(LIST))
     
        input.value = ''
        id++
        console.log(LIST)
        }
    }
    
})


lista.addEventListener('click',function(event){
    const element = event.target 
    const elementData = element.attributes.data.value
    console.log(elementData)
    
    if(elementData == 'realizado') {
        tareaRealizada(element)
    }
    else if(elementData == 'eliminado') {
        tareaEliminada(element)
        console.log("elimnado")
    }
    localStorage.setItem('TODO',JSON.stringify(LIST))
})




let data = localStorage.getItem('TODO')
if(data){
    LIST = JSON.parse(data)
    console.log(LIST)
    id = LIST.length
    cargarLista(LIST)
}else {
    LIST = []
    id = 0
}


function cargarLista(array) {
    array.forEach(function(item){
        agregarTarea(item.nombre,item.id,item.realizado,item.eliminado)
    })
}

//Seccion para reiniciar la lista

function toggleToDoItemState(event) {
  if (event.target.tagName === "LI") {
    event.target.classList.toggle("done");
  }
}

function clearCompleted(){
   let dones = document.getElementsByClassName('done')
   for(let i = 0; i < dones.length;i++){
   
      dones[i].style.display='none'
   }
}

clearBtn.addEventListener("click", clearCompleted);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
      <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
      <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
      <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
      <title>Easy List - Crea tu lista de compras</title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <!-Este es el container de todo weon->
        <div class="container">
          <div class="profile">
            <h1>Easy List Shop</h1>
          </div>
          <div class="add-product">
            <input type="text" id="input" placeholder="Agrega un producto, ejem: papas">
            <i id="boton-enter" class="fa fa-plus-circle"></i>
          </div>


          <div class="section-product">
            <h3>Productos por comprar </h3>
            <ul id="lista">

            </ul>
          </div>
          <div class="button-bottom" id="button_wrapper">
            <button id="save">Save list</button>
            <button id="clear">Clear completed</button>
            <button id="empty">Empty list</button>
          </div>
        </div>

    </body>

    </html>
```

Pero no logro hacer que funcionen.

Alguien que me pueda ayudar a explicar como arreglar el problema, ya busque videos en YT pero no encuentro nada.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: creo que se desacomodo mi pregunta la editare o simplemente haré otra publicacion (eliminando esta)

Comment: He editado juntando el JS con el HTML. No termina de funcionar por limitaciones de StackOverflow (no se puede acceder a localStorage), pero puedes editar de nuevo para eliminar esa parte que no parece jugar un papel relevante en tu problema. Te aconsejo crear un [mcve]. Este ejemplo sólo falla en que no es mínimo, así que yo editaría antes de crear un nueva pregunta desde cero

Comment: Creo que el problema es que cuando marcas una tarea como realizada no le añades al elemento la clase `done`, por lo que no encuentra elementos a borrar

Answer (score 0):

La función `toggleToDoItemState()` nunca es llamada, eso hace que no tengas ningún elemento con el ClassName = done, y que la variable `dones` de la función clearCompleted() su valor sea 0